# How do I remove a Map key that depends on user input inside a for loop?

Tags: java, hashmap, java.util.scanner

I'm fairly new to Java and I just started learning HashMap. My question is this: how do I remove a key in my `students` Map if it's inside a for loop and it depends on the user input? For easier visualization, please see my code below:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Map<String, String> students = new HashMap<>();
        
        for (int i = 1; i <=3; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter student number " + i + ": ");
            String stud_num = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter name " + i + ": ");
            String name = scan.nextLine();
            students.put(stud_num, name);
            //I want to remove a key here using students.remove(key)
        }
        
        for (Map.Entry e : students.entrySet()){
            System.out.println(e.getKey() + ": " + e.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What trouble are you having removing the entry?  It works for me with your code.  How are you intending on allowing the user to remove entries?  Maybe you need to add that choice to your menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For hasmap, to remove an item, please use the following (which I believe you already know)

```
students.remove(Data);
```

For your for loop, of course you are depending on the user's input to determine whether you want to Add (or delete) and item. You will need to let the system knows whether you want to remove (or just add). The normal way is to say add "Remove:[Data]" and when the system detects that there is "Remove:" in the user input, it will delete the "Data" from the map.

So in your for loop, please change

```
students.put(stud_num, name);
```

to

```
if name.contains("Remove:") {
String removestring = name.replace("Remove:","");
students.remove(removestring);
}
else {
students.put(stud_num, name);
}
```

To let user knows how to use it, please change your input prompt from "Enter name " to " Enter name (or enter [Remove:name] to remove)"